# EV Cert + Google Cloud HSM

Tags: google-cloud-platform, hsm, ev-certificate

As part of an automated build process, we are currently trying to get our EV Cert onto a Google Cloud HSM. Our Cert provider is dijicert. We've had several conversations with their technical support reps, but we keep getting conflicting answers. Right now the main problem we are having is generating a CSR that passes their website validation process.

Has anyone been able to use an EV Cert, and Google Cloud HSM as part of their automated
automated Windows code signing process?

Comment: 1) Your question lacks details to help you. 2) Your question mentions two different problems: a) generating a valid CSR; b) importing an EV certificate. Rewrite your question to present one well-defined problem. 3) Show the exact steps you followed and the problem that your CA (Digicert) has with the CSR. Detail how you are generating the CSR and the tool or library that is interfacing with the HSM to sign using the private key. 4) Cloud HSM does not support importing certificates. Use HSM for the private key and store the certificate (which is public) someplace else.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Hello, I am trying to achieve the same. Please, could you share how you solved your problem please? Thank you in advance